# CDI not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, glassfish, cdi

It is my first time trying out CDI. I have an Eclipse Kepler environment where I have a Maven Web project that is deployed on internal Glassfish 4.0 runtime.

It has a servlet and a JAX-RS resource POJO that both work fine. Next I created a class in the same package as the servlet and the JAX-RS POJO:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean {

  @Produces @ApplicationScoped
  public static Bean produce () {
    return new Bean();
  }

  public Bean () {
    Logger.getGlobal().info("Bean()");
  }

}
```

and I modified the POJO:

```
package com.example.test;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Resource(name = "foo", type = Rest.class)
@Path("/rest")
public class Rest {

  @Inject Bean b;

  @GET
  @Produces("text/html")
  public String f () {
    return "<h1>rest</h1>";
  }
}
```

When I access the POJO's rest path I get the message in Glassfish log:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[com.younum.web.test.App]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.example.test.App threw exception
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=Bean,parent=Rest,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1573724652)
```

That also shows up as an exception on the web page when I try to access the POJO.

What am I doing wrong? I feel that a web project somehow does not trigger the CDI and I am not sure what it takes to convert it to a Java EE project. The pom.xml is below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.younum.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem with the version of glassfish bundled with Eclipse Kepler m6. When I used a standalong Glassfish 4.0-b87 it worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

You need beans.xml file in your META-INF folder.
By default CDI is not enabled or activated when we deploy our project. So to activate it we need beans.xml file, it should reside under meta-inf folder.

Below is the sample beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Here is a good link to start 
http://oppansource.blogspot.in/2013/05/cdi-in-nutshell.html

Comment: well, not quite correct but upvoted because it helped. the standard allows multiple locations for beans.xml. glassfish is probably buggy.